# Python and Pygame: Avoiding creating display surface twice

Tags: python, variables, pygame, global, geometry-surface

Heyo, this is a bit of an extension of the "Imports within imports" question asked earlier by me, so moderators feel free to merge the 2.

I have 2 files: A.py and B.py

```
#A.py
import pygame
import B
pygame.init()
tv = pygame.display.set_mode((256, 256))
tv.blit(<some surface here>)


#B.py
import pygame
pygame.init()
tv.blit()??? <--- I need to blit to tv, but how do I do it here?
```

I've tried making a blank file called Globe and assigning global values to it, but most of the time I've found it just makes my code look clunky and hard to write. 
As well.. I don't want to `init` pygame twice either.
Is there any 'Pythonic' way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question could really apply to any structured python application.

An executable python script is going to have an entry-point. This is the script that you call to start the application. Within this script, it can import library modules to reuse extended functionality.

Your application needs to have a single entry point. Lets assume it will be `A.py`.
`B.py` would be a library module that you will import and use its functions. It should not have to expect a global `tv` variable to operate on. Instead, it should have, at the very least, functions that take arguments. Or even, a class that is instantiated with a surface to use. The benefit of this approach is that your `B` module is now reusable and not dependent on some executable main script providing a global surface always called `tv`

**B.py**

```
def blitSpecial(surf):
    surf.blit()
```

**A.py**

```
import B

tv = pygame.display.set_mode((256, 256))
B.blitSpecial(tv)
```

This is a good habit to get into. If all your modules depend on global objects from a main script, they will be far less reusable.

Specifically for your pygame situation, everything with the screen surface should be happening in `A.py` which is using all of the other modules for custom classes and utility functions.

Comment: Good answer. But it's really annoying to do stuff like:

dostuff(tv, main, houses, buildings, people, tiles)

Comment: @SuperDisk: I agree. Thats why you would try and write classes which are instantiated with properties. And the methods work on those properties. This was a very basic example of how write modules. As you can see in a lot of pygame examples, people subclass the existing classes to do custom stuff. Done right, you should not have to be calling a function with 10 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call `pygame.init()` once, so I think your code should look something like this:

```
#A.py
import pygame
import B

def setup():
    pygame.init()
    tv = pygame.display.set_mode((256, 256))
    ...
    mysurface = ...
    tv.blit(mysurface)
    return tv


#B.py
import pygame
def mydraw(surface):
    ...
    surface.blit()

# In whatever file you like :)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    surface_A = B.setup() # Do this first
    mydraw(surface_A)
```

Comment: I think you have some labels mixed up here? `setup()` is in your `A` module. Also, the docs say `init` is safe to call multiple times.

Comment: It's /safe/ to call multiple times but not necessary to do so.

Comment: In terms of whether `setup` should be in `A` or `B`, I think your answer is a little neater. I left it in `A` as the OP had `display.set_mode` in his `A.py`.

Comment: Ah, your example just reads differently. It looks like `if __name__` is part of your "B" definition, but really you are meaning that to be a 3rd module? Anyways, your actual point is correct. I was just mentioning something that looked like a simple typo.

Comment: Ah, well the `__main__` could be anywhere, indeed. These issues of code design are tricky, I think.

Comment: LOL. I'm not suggesting that it should be anywhere. I'm just saying your example reads like its part of your `B.py` as opposed to a 3rd file, which right now looks like a syntax problem. But whatever. You can leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can write functions that take pygame.Surface objects as parameters:

```
class TV():
    def __init__(self):
        self.img = ... 

        ### insert code to load image here

        self.rect = self.img.get_rect()

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.img, self.rect.topleft)

    def erase(self, surface, background):
        surface.blit(background, self.rect)
```

I don't personally know how fast/slow this is compared to other sprite-based engines, but it's a very quick way to build out a class that can draw/erase itself.

To use it, just create a display screen and a TV object.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((256, 256))     
background = pygame.Surface((0,0),(256,256))

background.fill(pygame.Color(0,0,0))
screen.fill(pygame.Color(0,0,0))

myTVobj = TV()
```

Every time you want to draw a copy of the TV onto the screen you call

```
myTVobj.draw(screen)
```

To erase the object, use

```
myTVobj.erase(screen, background)
```

Then you can do fun stuff later with objects created from the TV class, like stick them in a list.

```
tv_list = []
tv_list.append(myTVobj)
```

You can add a whole bunch of TVs to a list and draw all of them at the same time.

```
tv_list = []
tv_list.append(myTVobj)
tv_list.append(myTVobj)
tv_list.append(myTVobj)

for tv in tv_list:
    tv.draw(screen)
```

Or you can erase them all just by changing one line

```
for tv in tv_list:
    tv.erase(screen)
```

Finally, you can add one more function to your TV class that lets you move it around. If you treat the .rect member as a 'position marker', all you have to do is fiddle with its members (hehe) to change your object's onscreen update location.

```
def move(self, move_amount=(1,0):
    self.rect.move_ip(move_amount[0], move_amount[1])
```